# CakePHP, is there any way in find() method to use a MySQL WHERE...IN condition

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

As in the question is there any way in find() method to use a MySQL

```
WHERE...IN
```

condition. Eg.:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use conditions => array (field => array(values) ) like this

```
$conditions = array ( 'Model.field' => array (1,2,3,4) );

$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' =>$conditions) );
```

This will do a WHERE condition like this

```
SELECT ....
FROM ...
WHERE "Model".field IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: I had also found out that this will work too: `$conditions = array ( 'Model.field IN (1,2,3,4)' );`

Comment: but its not good coding. let cake handle it and just pass on the array

Comment: @23kulpamens yes, that will work, but as mark said. Is much better to let cake do the work. You may also use `$this->Model->query($query);` but is not the correct way since cake does a lot of check ups and work for you :D

Comment: Thanks for yours feed back :)